# How to abstract over a reference to a value or a value itself?

Tags: reference, rust

I have a trait that defines an interface for objects that can hold a value. The trait has a way of getting the current value:

```
pub trait HasValue<T> {
    fn get_current_value(&self) -> &T;
}
```

This is fine, but I realized that depending on the actual implementation, sometimes it's convenient to return a reference if `T` is stored in a field, and sometimes it's convenient to return a clone of `T` if the backing field was being shared across threads (for example). I'm struggling to figure out how to represent this in the trait. I could have something like this:

```
pub enum BorrowedOrOwned<'a, T: 'a> {
    Borrowed(&'a T),
    Owned(T)
}

impl<'a, T: 'a> Deref for BorrowedOrOwned<'a, T> {
    type Target = T;

    fn deref(&self) -> &T {
        use self::BorrowedOrOwned::*;

        match self {
            &Borrowed(b) => b,
            &Owned(ref o) => o,
        }
    }
}
```

And change `get_current_value()` to return a `BorrowedOrOwned<T>` but I'm not sure that this is idiomatic. `BorrowedOrOwned<T>` kind of reminds me of `Cow<T>` but since the point of `Cow` is to *copy-on-write* and I will be discarding any writes, that seems semantically wrong.

Is `Cow<T>` the correct way to abstract over a reference or an owned value? Is there a better way than `BorrowedOrOwned<T>`?

Comment: Would returning an associated type `B: Borrow<T>` work?

Comment: @ChrisEmerson I'm not sure what the tradeoffs of doing that would be so I'm unsure. Could you expand on that a bit? This seems like a question that could be generally useful so I'm interested in all answers even if they don't address my specific situation.

Comment: I think actually it doesn't really help directly; you still end up needing something like `Cow`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I suggest you use a `Cow`, since your `BorrowedOrOwned` has no difference to `Cow` except that it has fewer convenience methods. Anybody that gets a hold of a `BorrowedOrOwned` object could match on it and get the owned value or a mutable reference to it. If you want to prevent the confusion of being able to get a mutable reference or the object itself, the solution below applies, too.

For your use case i'd simply stay with `&T`, since there's no reason to make the API more complex. If a user wants a `usize`, when `T` is `usize`, they can simply dereference the reference.

An owned object only makes sense, if you expect the user to actually process it in an owned fashion. And even then, `Cow` is meant to abstract over big/heavy objects that you pass by ownership for the purpose of not requiring anyone to `clone` it. Your use case is the opposite, you want to pass small objects by ownership to prevent users from needing to copy small objects, and instead you are copying it.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. In simplifying the problem, I misstated my reasons for sometimes wanting to return a `&T` and other times needing to return a `T`. If the implementation stores `T` in an `Arc<Refcell<T>>` (for example) then it isn't possible to simply return a `&T`. `T` must be cloned and since the clone lives on the function's stack, you can't return a reference to it. I hope that's helpful.


PS. It was great talking to you at RBR :)

Comment: Ah! That makes more sense. Well.. I then suggest that your `BorrowedOrOwned` should be `enum Borrow<'a, T> { Ref(&'a T), Arc(Arc<RefCell<T>>), Rc(Rc<RefCell<T>>) }` or something along those lines. It's complicated by the `RefCell`, since many use cases might not want a `RefCell` in there, but without knowing more about the use case, I'd guess that would solve it.

Comment: Very true. I'll have to play around with it a bit but I'm going to mark this as the answer since you've answered my question about `Cow` and this has definitely pointed me in the right direction. Thanks

Comment: The term `Cow` is a bit confusing for new-comers, especially when dealing with read-only return values that you never intend to copy-from or write-to. While I was aware of `Cow` I was looking for something like `MaybeOwned`. But seems `Cow` is used for this too.