# Can I extend an iterator with values created inside a function?

Tags: rust, iterator

I have a [program](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=adcf4f24b49b69fbc6bd24fb431e29dd) which performs a `scan` operation on its argument:

```
struct A(usize);
struct B(usize);

fn scan_something<'a>(xs: &'a [A]) -> impl Iterator<Item = B> + 'a {
    let accum = 0;

    xs.iter().scan(accum, |accum, x| {
        *accum += x.0;
        Some(B(*accum))
    })
}
```

I want to extend the iterator with a few values generated inside the function:

```
fn scan_something<'a>(xs: &'a [A]) -> impl Iterator<Item = B> + 'a {
    let accum = 0;
    let head: A = A(xs.len());

    use std::iter::once;
    once(head).chain(xs.iter()).scan(accum, |accum, x| {
        *accum += x.0;
        Some(B(*accum))
    })
}
```

This doesn't compile because `once(head)` is an iterator of `A`, while `xs.iter()` is an iterator of `&A`.

I can implement `Clone` for `A` and put`.cloned()` after `xs.iter()` to fix this, but I don't want to clone the entire `xs` because it can be very long and `A` in the actual program is not cheap to clone.

I'm looking for a way to turn `once(head)` into an iterator of `&A`, but cannot find any method.

Is it possible to get it to work?

Comment: I think the best you can do is https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=5ecde66452279b0f186383d8ec61ac33, doesn't match the expected output because I miss calculated when I comment AR's answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Can I extend an iterator with values created inside a function?

Yes:

```
fn example<'a>(input: impl Iterator<Item = i32> + 'a) -> impl Iterator<Item = i32> + 'a {
    Some(42).into_iter().chain(input).chain(Some(99))
}

fn main() {
    for i in example(vec![1, 2, 3].into_iter()) {
        println!("{}", i);
    }
}
```

> I'm looking for a way to turn `once(head)` into an iterator of `&A`

Take a reference to the value:

```
iter::once(&head)
```

> Is it possible to get [this specific code] to work?

No. The compiler will even tell you that:

```
error[E0515]: cannot return value referencing local variable `head`
  --> src/lib.rs:10:5
   |
10 |       iter::once(&head).chain(xs.iter()).scan(accum, |accum, x| {
   |       ^          ----- `head` is borrowed here
   |  _____|
   | |
11 | |         *accum += x.0;
12 | |         Some(B(*accum))
13 | |     })
   | |______^ returns a value referencing data owned by the current function
```

See also:

- [Is there any way to return a reference to a variable created in a function?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32682876/155423)

> Is it possible to get [something close to this code] to work?

Maybe. Since `scan` starts with the accumulator value, you can just use that instead of sticking it onto the iterator:

```
fn scan_something<'a>(xs: &'a [A]) -> impl Iterator<Item = B> + 'a {
    xs.iter().scan(xs.len(), |accum, x| {
        *accum += x.0;
        Some(B(*accum))
    })
}
```

This would mean that the resulting iterator has one less item. If that's acceptable depends on your usage.

A more complicated solution is to have an enum that represents either a borrowed value or an owned value. You can then create an iterator of these enums from the input *and* the local value. The ownership of the local value is transferred to the returned iterator:

```
struct A(usize);
struct B(usize);

use std::iter;

// `A` doesn't implement `Clone`; if it did, use `Cow`
enum OwnedOrBorrowed<'a, T> {
    Owned(T),
    Borrowed(&'a T),
}

impl<'a, T> std::ops::Deref for OwnedOrBorrowed<'a, T> {
    type Target = T;
    fn deref(&self) -> &T {
        match self {
            OwnedOrBorrowed::Owned(t) => t,
            OwnedOrBorrowed::Borrowed(t) => t,
        }
    }
}

fn scan_something<'a>(xs: &'a [A]) -> impl Iterator<Item = B> + 'a {
    let accum = 0;
    let head = OwnedOrBorrowed::Owned(A(xs.len()));

    let borrowed = xs.iter().map(OwnedOrBorrowed::Borrowed);

    iter::once(head).chain(borrowed).scan(accum, |accum, x| {
        *accum += x.0;
        Some(B(*accum))
    })
}
```

This isn't free — every invocation of `scan`'s closure will perform conditional logic to test if the value is owned or borrowed.

See also:

- [Is it possible to return either a borrowed or owned type in Rust?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36706429/155423)
- [How to abstract over a reference to a value or a value itself?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41146267/155423)

Comment: @A.R I'm afraid I don't understand your question. Fundamentally, the OP wants to start with an iterator of references and add a new reference. That much is fine, but as soon as you return from the function, the reference to the local value would be invalidated and the compiler will prevent it. Moving the code around won't help as long as you try to return a reference to a local variable.

Comment: I found that what I wanted at first is an iterator which returns references to data owned by itself.
As long as I read posts like [this](https://medium.com/@jordan_98525/reference-iterators-in-rust-5603a51b5192) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30422177/how-do-i-write-an-iterator-that-returns-references-to-itself), it seems impossible.
This answer solved my problem, and for my real project, `Cow` fits best.

Comment: Yes, it is impossible to use `Iterator` to return references to yourself. Your question cannot do that anyway because the function's variables do not exist after the function exits. This answer sidesteps that by returning ownership of the variables *to the iterator*.