# Do I have to create distinct structs for both owned (easy-to-use) and borrowed (more efficient) data structures?

Tags: rust, borrowing, owned-types

I have a `Message<'a>` which has `&'a str` references on a *mostly* short-lived buffer.
Those references mandate a specific program flow as they are guaranteed to never outlive the lifetime `'a` of the buffer.

Now I also want to have an owned version of `Message`, such that it can be moved around, sent via threads, etc.

Is there an idiomatic way to achieve this? I thought that `Cow<'a, str>` might help, but unfortunately, `Cow` does not magically allocate in case `&'a str` would outlive the buffer's lifetime.

AFAIK, `Cow` is not special in the sense that no matter if `Cow` holds an `Owned` variant, it must still pass the borrow checker on `'a`.

Definition of `std::borrow::Cow`.

```rust
pub enum Cow<'a, B> {
    Borrowed(&'a B),
    Owned(<B as ToOwned>::Owned),
}
```

Is there an idiomatic way to have an owned variant of `Message`? For some reason we have `&str` and `String`, `&[u8]` and `Vec<u8>`, ... does that mean people generally would go for `&msg` and `Message`?

I suppose I still have to think about if an owned variant is really, really needed, but my experience shows that having an escape hatch for owned variants generally improves prototyping speed.

Comment: You can create a longer-lived `Cow` from a shorter-lived one: `let cow: Cow<'static, _> = Cow::Owned(cow.into_owned())`.

Comment: Would it work to make the string type itself a parameter to `Message`, so you could simply use `Message<&str>` most of the time, and `Message<String>` when that won't do?

Comment: @trentcl I think that's a reasonable solution for their problem, but there's still two separate types in the end ;-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you need to have multiple types, one representing the owned concept and one representing the borrowed concept.

You'll see the same technique throughout the standard library and third-party crates.

See also:

- [How to abstract over a reference to a value or a value itself?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41146267/155423)
- [How to avoid writing duplicate accessor functions for mutable and immutable references in Rust?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41436525/155423)